# OpenCV. Замена черного фона при вращении изображения

Tags: python, opencv

При вращении изображения, с помощью warpAffine, по краям появляется черный фон. Как сделать так, чтобы вместо черного фона отображалось другое изображение?

Comment: [mcve] помог бы сделать вопрос более понятным...

Comment: Вот пример из документации:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#rotation

Как видно размеры изображения, при повороте, не совпадают с размером вывода и появляется черный фон. Этот фон и хотелось бы поменять на другое изображение.

Comment: подопытный код лучше сразу добавлять в вопрос. — улучшает поиск и сразу понятно о чём речь, а также при написание ответа не надо изобретать собственный пример... Если кратко, то можно добавить альфа-канал (если нет) и прокрутить его вместе с изображением (или отдельно), а затем наложить результат на задний план с учётом маски из альфа-канала.